# EtherCAT Slave unable to transition from init state into preoperational state

Tags: ethercat

Good morning,

I am a beginner in EtherCAT and I have been trying to set up EtherCAT communication between IPC Beckhoff CP6202-0001 and some other devices (some of them are from Beckhoff and some of them not). My problem is that one of the devices (not from Beckhoff) is unable to transition from init state into pre-operational and then into operational state in the EtherCAT State Machine. The other devices behave normal and can transition into operational state. It is worthwile to say that I changed contain of the EEPROM in ET1100 in the "problematic" device. The .xml file that I used is most likely correct. Does anybody know where could be a mistake? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Without more specifics on the device that's failing I doubt anyone can help.  Usually an inability to get out of the Init state would indicate a device internal problem, since the requirements to reach the Pre-Operational state are mainly just the ability to read basic registers from the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A screenshot of your Twincat Device manager (expand devices tree) and specification of the the device you are using would help.

From what it sounds like you haven't configured the device correctly, which doesn't allow it go into OP Mode.